# XAML styler for Visual Studio 2022 not alphabetizing

Tags: xaml, maui, visual-studio-extensions

### Problem

I just installed the extension [XAML styler for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler2022), and it's not alphabetizing.  Other than that, it works fine (in that it formats).

### What I've made sure of / checked

- I've installed the latest version, correctly.
- Looking through the *Options >> XAML Styler* I don't see an option like "alphabetize".
- Just in case I messed up some option in the XAML styler editor that would remove the "alphabetize", I chose "reset to default" option, and I know that it worked because it changed "Keep first attribute on same line" from "true" (which is what I had set it at, my only change) to the default of "false".

Perhaps some other extension isn't playing well with this?  Here is an image of all of the extensions that I have (and "proof" that XAML styler is installed correctly):
[image]

You'll see that I have two updates available -- they have nothing to do with XAML styler (they're for LiveShare and ML.NET Model Builder 2022).

What else can I check?  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: File an issue on their repo - https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/issues

Comment: @Jason Yeah, that's probably the thing to do.  I'm probably an edge case in some way, shape or form.